# Class taking itself as a parameter of the constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've seen similar questions but most of the time it doesn't have the same implications or nuances

```
public class Dog {
  public Dog(Animal animal) {
    this.name = animal.name;
    this.age = animal.age;
    ....
  }
  public Dog(Dog dog) {
    this.name = dog.name;
    this.age = dog.name;
  }
}
```

I saw this written by a colleague on several occasions in different contexts but have yet to see any value in the second constructor...  I was wondering if there were any reasons why this type of structure pattern is good/bad/otherwise.

Comment: Note that [constructor overloading in conjunction with Dependency Injection is anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [copy constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx).

The idea is that the object should know how to make a clone of itself if there is a need for that in consuming code - i.e., simply providing a reference to an existing object is not desirable.

Personally, I've never felt that I needed one, and I feel that they could be abused or misused by other developers with a non-trivial memory footprint that grows linearly with the size of the class itself.

Creation and use of a read-only wrapper class that implements one or more common interfaces may be a desirable substitute in many instances where this pattern may be used.

Comment: thanks for the reply, your point of rarely needing one and abuse of such is probably why it feels so wrong.  The term also helped in searching :D